# GraphQL Github API formatting

Tags: graphql, github-api, apollo

I am wondering how to deal with the following problem. I am using GraphQL to query the v4 Github API with the following query:

```
{
  viewer {
    repositories(first: 30) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gets me a response that looks like so:

```
{
    "data": {
        "viewer": {
            "repositories": {
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "node": {
                            "name": "test-repo"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "node": {
                            "name": "another-repo"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty new to GraphQL, I understand that in my query I need to provide the edges and nodes but I would rather get a response back in this kind of way because I am not interested to know about "edges" and "nodes" in my frontend:

```
{
    "data": {
        "viewer": {
            "repositories": [
                    {
                        "name": "test-repo"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "another-repo"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing this kind of response is normal for GraphQL but it would be pretty cumbersome to rewrite to response all the time for easier usage in my frontend. Is there some way to emit the "edges" and "nodes" and get the formatting that I would like or is this simply all up to me to deal with?

I have looked at some libraries like [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/) but I have no idea is this is a right fit to deal with things like this. Hopefully someone a bit more experienced with GraphQL could tell me something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, services provides two endpoints: Relay endpoint (with edges and nodes) and simple endpoint.

Looks like GitHub only have a Relay endpoint. In this case, the only thing you can do is to manually format the response on your frontend.

Actually, such complex response structure is needed because we often need to do a pagination. Take a look at the example:

```
{
    getArticle(id: "some-id") {
        id
        userId
        user {
            id
            name
        }
        tags(first: 10, after: "opaqueCursor") {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    name
                    itemsCount
                }
            }
            pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
                hasPreviousPage
                endCursor
                startCursor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`pageInfo` is located at the same level as `edges`.

So if you later will need to do a pagination, it would be better to keep the response format as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `edges` query if you know you aren't searching along those relationships. Cursor-based pagination will work by checking the `pageInfo` value `hasNextPage` and using `endCursor` as the `after` query parameter:

```
 viewer {
      repositories(first: 30,after:"<CURSOR_STRING>") {
        totalCount
        pageInfo{
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
        nodes{
          name
        }
      }
    }
```

returns

```
"viewer": {
  "repositories": {
    "totalCount": 38,
    "pageInfo": {
      "hasNextPage": true,
      "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOAl/5mw=="
    },
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "AllStarRoom"
      },
      {
        "name": "shimsham"
      },
      {
        "name": "Monitor-Docs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```